# query to get records that have most recent date

Tags: query, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

How can I make data that looks like this:

```
Job_Id  Monitor_Date
B119    3/11/2010
B119    3/07/2013
B119    15/05/2020
B121    03/05/2015
B167    3/12/2010
B167    3/07/2013
B167    15/10/2015
B189    31/07/2015
B189    07/05/2015
```

Look like this - so that only 1 record for each Job_ID and it is the most recent Monitor_Date:

```
Job_Id  Monitor_Date
B119    15/05/2020
B121    13/05/2015
B167    15/10/2015
B189    7/05/2020
```

Comment: Specify your DBMS precisely, including its version.

Comment: and if possible no pictures - use text so helpers can easily copy your sample data to sqlfiddle or test programs ....

Comment: Are you storing your "dates" as strings? It looks like it because in your sample data you have "dates" where the first component have both leading zeros and without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Job_Id, MAX(Monitor_Date) Monitor_Date
FROM source_table
GROUP BY Job_Id
```

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the order by to define the returned order from the select.
MS SQL you can use 'top 4' and Oracle I think it's rowcount to limit the returned rows.
The SQL engine would have to understand the monitor date column so if its a text field you would have to convert it to date during the query using a function like todate(3/11/10, xxx).

Comment: anybody using varchar or similar to store date / datetime deserves to be nailed onto a cross